# Trying to unnest a column of type Text[] is skipping the columns that are null - Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, unnest

Imagine a table that looks like this:

```
    name | reloptions
-----------------------
    testname | {val1, val2}
   nullSample | null
```

if I run a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table, UNNEST(reloptions) AS reloption
```

I only get :

```
name | reloption
------------------
testname | val1
testname | val2
```

I need the result set to still include the row that has the null value:

```
     name | reloption
    ------------------
    testname | val1
    testname | val2
    nullSample | null
```

Any help is appreciated in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `coalesce()` to replace the `NULL` value with an array with one element which is `NULL`.

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat AS t
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL unnest(coalesce(t.reloptions, '{null}'::text[])) AS ro
                                                                                   (ro);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=47fb13ceb082249786af615d9e1679a7)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `left join`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t LEFT JOIN LATERAL
     UNNEST(t.reloptions) AS reloption
     ON 1=1;
```